# DHCPD and Appamor

Tags: networking, server, permissions, dhcp

I running ubuntu 22.04 on raspberry pi, with fixed IPv4 address. On the server a isc-dhcp-server is running. (i know isc-dhcp-server is outdated an not in service anymore).

While starting appamor denying dhcpd operation:

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/dhcpd" name="/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range"
```

That's not a problem, because of fixed IPv4 address, but why and how can i prevent this failed operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent the message:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd

@{PROC}/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range r,
```